# Debugging/removing excess notifications

Tags: iphone, notifications

I have a lot of one-to-many notification needs in my app, so I'm constantly posting notifications for other objects to receive.
I was curious if anyone has a good method for debugging the contents of the default notification queue, aside from putting print statements in all my selectors.  I'm sure I have a lot of functions that are called multiple times because I forget to remove them from the queue and add duplicates.  I just need a good way to go through everything and figure out which ones are the culprits.